# Изменить ширину и диапзон колебаний в canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Всем привет, решил добавить себе на страницу такой код канваса. Но столкнулся с такой проблемкой. Как изменить начало и конец линии? Вначале и в конце слишком длинный отрезок прямой линии. Не подскажете где находится параметр, который отвечает за это? нашел, как менять параметры внутренних линий, но внешние не знаю как.

Как вставить данный вариант на страницу? и как адаптировать его? на мобильных устройствах нормально будет смотреться?

В идеале эта штука должна быть полностью волнистая и плавно менять цвета, но я че то хз как
Если что , вот вариант в ссылке https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BMLoYp

```js
/**
 * Generates multiple customizable animated sines waves
 * using a canvas element. Supports retina displays and
 * limited mobile support
 *
 * I've created a seperate library based on this pen. 
 * Check it out at https://github.com/isuttell/sine-waves
 */
function SineWaveGenerator(options) {
  $.extend(this, options || {});
  
  if(!this.el) { throw "No Canvas Selected"; }
  this.ctx = this.el.getContext('2d');
  
  if(!this.waves.length) { throw "No waves specified"; }
  
  // Internal
  this._resizeWidth();
  window.addEventListener('resize', this._resizeWidth.bind(this));
  // User
  this.resizeEvent();
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizeEvent.bind(this));
  
  if(typeof this.initialize === 'function') {
    this.initialize.call(this);
  }
  // Start the magic
  this.loop();
}

// Defaults
SineWaveGenerator.prototype.speed = 10;
SineWaveGenerator.prototype.amplitude = 50;
SineWaveGenerator.prototype.wavelength = 50;
SineWaveGenerator.prototype.segmentLength = 10;

SineWaveGenerator.prototype.lineWidth = 2;
SineWaveGenerator.prototype.strokeStyle  = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)';

SineWaveGenerator.prototype.resizeEvent = function() {};

// fill the screen
SineWaveGenerator.prototype._resizeWidth = function() {
  this.dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 10;
  
  this.width = this.el.width = window.innerWidth * this.dpr;
  this.height = this.el.height = window.innerHeight * this.dpr;
  this.el.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
  this.el.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
  
  this.waveWidth = this.width * 0.55;
  this.waveLeft = this.width * 0.25;
}

SineWaveGenerator.prototype.clear = function () {
  this.ctx.clearRect(1, 0, this.width, this.height);
}

SineWaveGenerator.prototype.time = 0;

SineWaveGenerator.prototype.update = function(time) {  
  this.time = this.time - 0.007;
  if(typeof time === 'undefined') {
    time = this.time;
  }

  var index = -1;
  var length = this.waves.length;

  while(++index < length) {
    var timeModifier = this.waves[index].timeModifier || 1;
    this.drawSine(time * timeModifier, this.waves[index]);
  }
  index = void 0;
  length = void 0;
}

// Constants
var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
var HALFPI = Math.PI / 2;

SineWaveGenerator.prototype.ease = function(percent, amplitude) {
  return amplitude * (Math.sin(percent * PI2 - HALFPI) + 1) * 0.9;
}

SineWaveGenerator.prototype.drawSine = function(time, options) {
  options = options || {};
  amplitude = options.amplitude || this.amplitude;
  wavelength = options.wavelength || this.wavelength;
  lineWidth = options.lineWidth || this.lineWidth;
  strokeStyle = options.strokeStyle || this.strokeStyle;
  segmentLength = options.segmentLength || this.segmentLength;
  
  var x = time;
  var y = 0;  
  var amp = this.amplitude;
 
  // Center the waves
  var yAxis = this.height / 2; 
  
  // Styles
  this.ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth * this.dpr;
  this.ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
  this.ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  this.ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
  this.ctx.beginPath();
  
  // Starting Line
  this.ctx.moveTo(0, yAxis);
  this.ctx.lineTo(this.waveLeft, yAxis);
  
  for(var i = 0; i < this.waveWidth; i += segmentLength) {
    x = (time * this.speed) + (-yAxis + i) / wavelength; 
    y = Math.sin(x); 
    
    // Easing
    amp = this.ease(i / this.waveWidth, amplitude); 
    
    this.ctx.lineTo(i + this.waveLeft, amp * y + yAxis);
    
    amp = void 0;
  }
  
  // Ending Line
  this.ctx.lineTo(this.width, yAxis);
  
  // Stroke it
  this.ctx.stroke();
  
  // Clean up
  options = void 0;
  amplitude = void 0;
  wavelength = void 0;
  lineWidth = void 0;
  strokeStyle = void 0;
  segmentLength = void 0;
  x = void 0;
  y = void 0;
} 

SineWaveGenerator.prototype.loop = function() {
  this.clear();
  this.update();
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));
}

new SineWaveGenerator({
  el: document.getElementById('waves'),
  
  speed: 8,
  
  waves: [
    {
      timeModifier: 1,
      lineWidth: 3,
      amplitude: 150,
      wavelength: 200,
      segmentLength: 20,
//       strokeStyle: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)'
    },
    {
      timeModifier: 1,
      lineWidth: 2,
      amplitude: 250,
      wavelength: 200,
//       strokeStyle: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)'
    },
    {
      timeModifier: 1,
      lineWidth: 3,
      amplitude: -150,
      wavelength: 50,
      segmentLength: 10,
//       strokeStyle: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
    },
    {
      timeModifier: 1,
      lineWidth: 1,
      amplitude: -100,
      wavelength: 100,
      segmentLength: 20,
//       strokeStyle: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'
    }
  ],
  
  initialize: function (){

  },
  
  resizeEvent: function() {
    var gradient = this.ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, this.width, 1);
    gradient.addColorStop(0,"rgba(254, 255, 255, 0)");
    gradient.addColorStop(0.5,"rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)");
    gradient.addColorStop(1,"rgba(255, 255, 254, 0)");
    
    var index = -1;
    var length = this.waves.length;
   while(++index < length){
      this.waves[index].strokeStyle = gradient;
    }
    
    // Clean Up
    index = void 0;
    length = void 0;
    gradient = void 0;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #2F2F31;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #2F2F31;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #2F2F31;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #2F2F31;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="waves"></canvas>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
/**
 * Generates multiple customizable animated sines waves
 * using a canvas element. Supports retina displays and
 * limited mobile support
 *
 * I've created a seperate library based on this pen. 
 * Check it out at https://github.com/isuttell/sine-waves
 */
function SineWaveGenerator(options) {
  $.extend(this, options || {});
  
  if(!this.el) { throw "No Canvas Selected"; }
  this.ctx = this.el.getContext('2d');
  
  if(!this.waves.length) { throw "No waves specified"; }
  
  // Internal
  this._resizeWidth();
  window.addEventListener('resize', this._resizeWidth.bind(this));
  // User
  this.resizeEvent();
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizeEvent.bind(this));
  
  if(typeof this.initialize === 'function') {
    this.initialize.call(this);
  }
  // Start the magic
  this.loop();
}

// Defaults
SineWaveGenerator.prototype.speed = 10;
SineWaveGenerator.prototype.amplitude = 50;
SineWaveGenerator.prototype.wavelength = 50;
SineWaveGenerator.prototype.segmentLength = 10;

SineWaveGenerator.prototype.lineWidth = 2;
SineWaveGenerator.prototype.strokeStyle  = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)';

SineWaveGenerator.prototype.resizeEvent = function() {};

// fill the screen
SineWaveGenerator.prototype._resizeWidth = function() {
  this.dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 10;
  
  this.width = this.el.width = window.innerWidth * this.dpr;
  this.height = this.el.height = window.innerHeight * this.dpr;
  this.el.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
  this.el.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
  /* 
здесь вы можете изменить 
   отступ слева - waveLeft , 
   и саму длину волны -  waveWidth.
  Для вас подойдет например: 
  this.waveWidth = this.width * 0.9;
  this.waveLeft = this.width * 0.05;*/


  this.waveWidth = this.width * 0.55;
  this.waveLeft = this.width * 0.25;
}

SineWaveGenerator.prototype.clear = function () {
  this.ctx.clearRect(1, 0, this.width, this.height);
}

SineWaveGenerator.prototype.time = 0;

SineWaveGenerator.prototype.update = function(time) {  
  this.time = this.time - 0.007;
  if(typeof time === 'undefined') {
    time = this.time;
  }

  var index = -1;
  var length = this.waves.length;

  while(++index < length) {
    var timeModifier = this.waves[index].timeModifier || 1;
    this.drawSine(time * timeModifier, this.waves[index]);
  }
  index = void 0;
  length = void 0;
}

// Constants
var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
var HALFPI = Math.PI / 2;

SineWaveGenerator.prototype.ease = function(percent, amplitude) {
  return amplitude * (Math.sin(percent * PI2 - HALFPI) + 1) * 0.9;
}

SineWaveGenerator.prototype.drawSine = function(time, options) {
  options = options || {};
  amplitude = options.amplitude || this.amplitude;
  wavelength = options.wavelength || this.wavelength;
  lineWidth = options.lineWidth || this.lineWidth;
  strokeStyle = options.strokeStyle || this.strokeStyle;
  segmentLength = options.segmentLength || this.segmentLength;
  
  var x = time;
  var y = 0;  
  var amp = this.amplitude;
 
  // Center the waves
  var yAxis = this.height / 2; 
  
  // Styles
  this.ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth * this.dpr;
  this.ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
  this.ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  this.ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
  this.ctx.beginPath();
  
  // Starting Line
  this.ctx.moveTo(0, yAxis);
  this.ctx.lineTo(this.waveLeft, yAxis);
  
  for(var i = 0; i < this.waveWidth; i += segmentLength) {
    x = (time * this.speed) + (-yAxis + i) / wavelength; 
    y = Math.sin(x); 
    
    // Easing
    amp = this.ease(i / this.waveWidth, amplitude); 
    
    this.ctx.lineTo(i + this.waveLeft, amp * y + yAxis);
    
    amp = void 0;
  }
  
  // Ending Line
  this.ctx.lineTo(this.width, yAxis);
  
  // Stroke it
  this.ctx.stroke();
  
  // Clean up
  options = void 0;
  amplitude = void 0;
  wavelength = void 0;
  lineWidth = void 0;
  strokeStyle = void 0;
  segmentLength = void 0;
  x = void 0;
  y = void 0;
} 

SineWaveGenerator.prototype.loop = function() {
  this.clear();
  this.update();
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));
}

new SineWaveGenerator({
  el: document.getElementById('waves'),
  
  speed: 8,
  
  waves: [
    {
      timeModifier: 1,
      lineWidth: 3,
      amplitude: 150,
      wavelength: 200,
      segmentLength: 20,
//       strokeStyle: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)'
    },
    {
      timeModifier: 1,
      lineWidth: 2,
      amplitude: 250,
      wavelength: 200,
//       strokeStyle: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)'
    },
    {
      timeModifier: 1,
      lineWidth: 3,
      amplitude: -150,
      wavelength: 50,
      segmentLength: 10,
//       strokeStyle: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
    },
    {
      timeModifier: 1,
      lineWidth: 1,
      amplitude: -100,
      wavelength: 100,
      segmentLength: 20,
//       strokeStyle: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'
    }
  ],
  
  initialize: function (){

  },
  
  resizeEvent: function() {
    var gradient = this.ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, this.width, 1);
    gradient.addColorStop(0,"rgba(254, 255, 255, 0)");
    gradient.addColorStop(0.5,"rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)");
    gradient.addColorStop(1,"rgba(255, 255, 254, 0)");
    
    var index = -1;
    var length = this.waves.length;
   while(++index < length){
      this.waves[index].strokeStyle = gradient;
    }
    
    // Clean Up
    index = void 0;
    length = void 0;
    gradient = void 0;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #2F2F31;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #2F2F31;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #2F2F31;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #2F2F31;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="waves"></canvas>
```

Comment: Измените значения this.waveWidth и this.waveLeft на:
this.waveWidth = this.width * 0.9;
this.waveLeft = this.width * 0.05;

Comment: Чтобы вставить на страницу, просто скопируйте весь код.

Comment: сделал таким образом,а как сделать так, чтобы начиналось и заканчивалось одновременно, я так понял, там параметр left задает начало движения волн, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BMLoYp

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут все зашито, сделайте вот так:

```
this.waveWidth = this.width * 1; // длина линии
this.waveLeft = this.width * 0; // левое положение
```

Comment: сделал таким образом,а как сделать так, чтобы начиналось и заканчивалось одновременно, я так понял, там параметр left задает начало движения волн, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BMLoYp

Comment: `this.waveWidth = this.width * 1;` означает что закончится в конце экрана, умножайте на значение меньше единицы и оно будет смещаться от конца экрана.

Comment: точно!спасибо мужик!ты мозг!)

Comment: Если вопрос закрыт стоит ответить как решение вопроса, галочкой. Иначе "дух общества" будет поднимать тему вверх.